# Getting interface methods from a dynamically loaded class in .NET

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies, dllimport, reflection.emit

I've got a .dll library I'm writing that interfaces with a proprietary COM assembly.  My goal is to publish my work online once it's built, however I need to remove the COM assembly as a project reference to avoid distribution of this proprietary dll.  So what I'm trying to be able to do is dynamically load the assembly at runtime, and invoke methods where I need them.  Traditionally I've used object reflection for unknown types, however this can get slow at times, and involves several ugly instanciations.  In .NET 4.0 is there a way to cleanly get all the methods and toss them into a dynamic class/interface at runtime?

I'm currently getting the object like this:

```
Type myClassType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyClass.Myclass.1");
object classObj = Activator.CreateInstance(myClassType);
```

I thought I'd be able to use Type.GetMethods(), however it only returns the generic ones (Equals, ToString, GetLifetime..., etc.).  I know the class uses an interface, so I tried looking into dynamically loading the interface also.  That led me to Reflection.Emit, and the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, which I am failing to understand so far.

If there's a way for me to invoke methods without needing to throw a bunch of BindingFlags every few lines, I'd greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction

I do have the GUID for both the Class and the Interface if that helps at all.

Comment: Take a look at this Stackoverflow posting and see if the alternative to using Reflection might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422786/alternative-to-reflection

Comment: This is all pretty normal when you use late binding.  Use the *dynamic* keyword to make writing that code less painful.

Comment: Hans, that might be the direction I end up going. I'll just have to manually create a lot more types from ProgIds than I wanted to, and I wont have any intellisense (which may be a good thing considering the proprietary dll is crap in the first place).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were at your situation(and if i have understand the problem correctly):
I would separate the Interface,s library (DLL) from implementation library(DLL)
Then the implementation library would be loaded dynamically and my main source code that is
referenced to Interface library would be complied

```
Type myClassType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyClass.Myclass.1");
myClassIntrface classObj = 
   Activator.CreateInstance(myClassType) as myClassIntrface;
classObj.CallSomeInterfaceMethod();
```

hope this will be useful pal.

Comment: This is pretty much what I ended up doing.  Thanks for the response.